# Sorted according to the first three letters of the data pulled from the database?

Tags: php, database

How can i sort the data pulled from the database according to the fist three or five or etc letters?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM macyayin ORDER BY channel, country";
```

for example for this example. I want to sort according to firt three letters of channel..

Comment: Why does sorting by the first three letters rather than the whole channel make such a difference? ORDER BY SUBSTRING(channel,1,3), country; or ORDER BY SUBSTRING(channel FROM 1 FOR 3), country; depending on your flavour of database

Comment: @Firat - I'm not sure what sense this would make? All you do is introduce uncertainty in the sort order, as you can no longer predict whether `Tomato` or `Tomatoes` or `Tomato juice` will come first. Is that really what you want?

Comment: ORDER BY SUBSTRING(`channel`,0 , 3)?

Comment: @Oliver - MySQL substring offsets start at 1

Comment: `ORDER BY LEFT(channel, 3)` lets list all possible solutions in comments instead of answers.

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry, was in php mode. :-)

Comment: The values are already sorted by the ORDER BY clause in the query.  So, once the data have been "pulled" from the database the client app doesn't need to do anything to sort them. The question makes no sense as asked.

Comment: i added time and after channel name like "15:00 cnn", so i want to sort by time. and its first 5 characters. and its okay. "ORDER BY SUBSTRING(channel FROM 1 FOR 3), country;" thank you so much to all.. :)

Comment: Better to put the time into its own column rather than affixing it to the channel name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT left(channel,3) as ch,channel,country FROM macyayin ORDER BY ch";
```